# Why only one delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've read that an object can only have one delegate at once.
But is that really true?

Let's say I make an object with a protocol and from that object I want to gather a lot of data from several other objects. I add every object that conforms to my protocol to an array. Then I just loop through it and call my methods on every delegate.

```
NSMutableArray *collectFromDelegates = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//in delegateArray I keep pointers to every delegate.
for(id delegate in delegateArray){
  [collectFromDelegates addObject:[delegate someProtocolMethod]];
}
```

Is this wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not really [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

> Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object. The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it. The message informs the delegate of an event that the delegating object is about to handle or has just handled.

It doesn't make much sense to have more than one object handle an event for you, since it has already been handled. The only reason I could see to have multiple delegates is that if the first fails to handle an event, it can be passed to the next, continuing until some object handles it.

In your example, the objects are acting as data sources. This makes more sense than multiple delegates, but could easily be implemented by having a single data source combine data from multiple objects, which means the object asking for the data doesn't have to worry about how to combine it.

The other case where you would often want multiple objects is receiving notifications of an event. This is not delegation because the objects are not working for the object, just acting on something that happened to the object. This is better implemented using notifications or observing.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's convention is to only have one "delegate" object.  But you can set up your own class to have an array of delegates if that's what you need.  You might want to call them something else for clarity.

In your example, calling them "dataSources" might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is just an abstract concept - you can have as many delegates as you want. However, this is rarely required and often a poor pattern.

Apple make good use of a `source` and `delegate` pattern. Source ivars (a form of delegate) provide data, while delegate ivars are invoked for logical responses. Perhaps this is a better solution?

Alternatively you can use `NSNotification` to inform many listeners of a single event.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A class only really needs one delegate, if you have more than one you are solving a different problem. The delegate pattern is used to modify the behaviour of a class. Say for instance we have a Dog class which can bark, but different types of dogs bark in different way. A delegate would be one way of changing the barking behaviour.

If you need more than one you are probably more interested in OBSERVING what your class is doing, it needs to NOTIFY others of current EVENTS. As several other classes might be interested in the behaviour of one you would need an array. In iOS SDK this is already done for you with notifications. This is called the Observer pattern.

Different use cases...

Answer (score 1):

> I've read that an object can only have one delegate at once. But it's that really true?

Where did you read that?  No, it's not true.  For instance, `UITableView` has two delegates, one to supply the data, the other to handle actions.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you want to message multiple classes that are interested in what you class does, you would use `NSNotification`s. That will however not allow them to return data unless you allow them to send a message to the `object` of the notification. I'm not sure if that would be a cleaner solution though.

Answer (score 0):

One approach beside the mentioned Notifications could be, that your delegate implementation holds an array of objects conforming to the protocol and calls the protocols method on this as a wrapper.